# The term docker is not recognized in the octopus work env

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, octopus-deploy

I’m trying to run a script from the package on the AWS CLI script but it happens to be failing :frowning: even though it worked when using the inline script! I have attached the error message below, pls if someone could help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error message is clear -> there is no **docker** cmd available for caller. Double check couple of things:

- Target machine is correct (Are you sure you want to run docker cmd on *that* machine? I have the experience that by mistake I've used wrong tentacle as a target - using wrong target role tag)
- Docker is installed on target machine
- Tentacle is running under user/account that does have docker cmd available